# Drupal import audio failed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-feeds

I use Media Feeds to import 900 audio files.

Configuration are set up correctly but i've a message error in import step :

"Failed to get the file object for /sites/all/files/audios/categorie1/xxxx.mp3"

For exemple in XML, Audio file path is /sites/all/files/audios/categorie1/xxxx.mp3

I don't understand why it failed...

Someone can explain me? & tell me how to import all audios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download "[feedtamper](http://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper)" module in drupal7.

Go to **admin-structure > feedimporters > tamper** in that you can see the fields in tamper.

Click "**add plugin**" then "**The plugin to add**" to select "**Rewrite**" do for all fields.

Under that you can see "**configuration rewrite**" in that type "**public://**" + **Available Replacement Patterns** it avoid "public://".

Then Go to **Admin-structure > Content type > your content type > manage fields** to click "**which field is using for storing mp3**".

"**Allowed file extensions**" check "**mp3**" is typed or not.

"**Maximum upload size**" type into "**50 MB**"

Click "**save settings**"

Must cache clear.

Answer (score 0):

I never used this module, but I guess it should look for file *sites/all/files/audios/categorie1/xxxx.mp3* and not */sites/all/files/audios/categorie1/xxxx.mp3* (without / at the beginning).

Comment: I tried to change the file url in XML with public:// or absolute URL but it still doesn't work

Comment: I change settings. I use Audio (media_internet) & I change in xml the path of file to set it with url. Now i've another yellow message : 

Unable to add file http://www.etc...

Comment: Hi

I tried to "cut" my bulk upload in 2 step.

1st, I used media import to import audio files. (It will upload all audio with right settings)
Then I used feed xml & in my xml I change url file by : public://test.mp3

So my audio is already in drupal BUT I've still a green message :

Failed to get the file object for public://20110313_tariq_aboul_wafa_tafsir_youssef.mp3.
Created 1 nœud.